# MaterialDialog won't show after 2nd invokation

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am having issues to comprehend why this, in general, great library called [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) is failing me:

```
private MaterialDialog wifiDialog;

@Override
public void showWiFiDialog() {

    if (wifiDialog != null) {
        wifiDialog.dismiss();
        wifiDialog = null;
    }

    wifiDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("Please activate WiFi")
            .contentColor(Color.BLACK)
            .content(R.string.wifi_dialog_content)
            .positiveText("Settings")
            .positiveColor(Color.BLACK)
            .negativeText("Exit")
            .negativeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .cancelable(false)
            .onPositive((dialog, which) -> startActivityForResult(new Intent(ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS))
            .onNegative((dialog, which) -> finish())
            .build();

    wifiDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void hideWifiDialog() {
    if (wifiDialog != null) {
        wifiDialog.dismiss();
        wifiDialog = null;
    }
}
```

When calling:

1. showWiFiDialog() -> shows as expected
2. hideWifiDialog() -> hides as expected
3. showWifiDialog() -> sometimes, with a bit of luck
4. hideWifiDialog() -> sometimes, but requires even more luck

To sum up: When calling show and hide for the first time, it all works as expected. Whenever calling it more than once, the behavior becomes non-deterministic. I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need to re-initialize `MaterialDialog` each time you want to show it. Let's see if below code makes difference.

```
private MaterialDialog wifiDialog;

@Override
public void showWiFiDialog() {

    if (wifiDialog != null) {
        wifiDialog.dismiss();
    }else{

    wifiDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("Please activate WiFi")
            .contentColor(Color.BLACK)
            .content(R.string.wifi_dialog_content)
            .positiveText("Settings")
            .positiveColor(Color.BLACK)
            .negativeText("Exit")
            .negativeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .cancelable(false)
            .onPositive((dialog, which) -> startActivityForResult(new Intent(ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS))
            .onNegative((dialog, which) -> finish())
            .build();
    }

    wifiDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void hideWifiDialog() {
    if (wifiDialog != null) {
        wifiDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, as it also seemed more logical to me. And you are correct, I do not have to reinitialize it every time, the behaviour is exactly the same; that is, if the dialog shows or not is solely dependent on luck.